# How to fix bootstrap tab overflow?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just noticed bootstrap tabs overflow if you zoom in/out. You can see it live on their [site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) by zooming in and hovering over one of the non-active tabs.

I switched to bootstrap tabs because I had this exact same problem when doing tabs myself. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2L7odj5q/) is a fiddle to mess around with. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

```
.
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice and easy answer would be to use `translateY`. Just add

```
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-1px);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-1px);
    -o-transform:translateY(-1px);
    transform:translateY(-1px);
}
```

The issue remains that the whole text translates. I see that just as a nice effect. This is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L7odj5q/1/).

Hope it helps.